# Is there a point and shoot that offers "on-camera" creative photography features as in cellphone apps?

Tags: point-and-shoot, cameraphones

Generally I enjoy using cellphone apps such as kitcam or hipstematic.
But I want a better camera.
I would like to be able to control DoF, aperture and iso, but I would like to see the result with the filters while shooting.
Is there a good p&s that offers a nice set of features as in cellphone apps?
Thanks.

Comment: Latest Samsung cameras as well as Nikon Coolpix 800 use Android as their operating system, which I can imagine, will allow to program custom post-processing filters just like apps.

Comment: Honestly, it is never something I've looked at since these things are irreversible and can always be replicated with flexibility on a computer with the right software. I do know that Casio is big on those types of features but you'll have to do some digging.

Comment: @PavloDyban - The disconnect is that for example, you may have Instagram installed on the Nikon Coolpix S800c(Android), but it is a _separate_ app then the Nikon "Shooing" app. You can't control aperture _inside_ of Instagram since Instagram doesn't support that. So essentially what the user is asking for is a camera that works just like Instragram in that it has previews of filters during the shoot, but also has full manual controls. I don't know of anything that exists such as this quite yet.

Comment: @dpollitt My first compact camera Sony DSC W300 has had b/w & sepia modi which were applied instantly & irreversibly.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the current generation of pocket-size point-and-shoots have some features of that nature, although the names for each mode might change by manufacturer. (In fact, some DSLRs do as well -- Canon started including them on the T3i.) One thing I've noted is that in some cases, the camera doesn't degrade the image enough to be convincing; the toy camera mode on my Canon A2200, for example, doesn't change the optics of the image like a plastic lens would, and the bluescale mode looks great but isn't a particularly convincing mock-cyanotype.

My personal take on the matter: fix it in post. The features are going to be there on most brands, but you don't gain much from it.

Also, you asked about changing DoF and the like. I'm not sure about most brands, but for Canon cameras, CHDK does let you tweak the aperture, so that's something to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

My sony rx-100 has some picture effects (toy, black and white, selective color, miniature, HDR, soft focus,...) and some of them are visible while shooting.

Here's a YouTube link showing the modes http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDly1wOB0X8